# NSInvalidArgumentException on iOS device

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

[NSInvalidArgumentException on iOS device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5deW6.png)

I'm getting this error when I try to run my expo app on my iPhone. I have a lot of files and not sure what is this and where is it coming from. If anyone knows, please help me. As soon as I run the app, the app crashes.

Comment: You're calling a class method 'length' on a boolean object. So search you project for something like 'length]' and you'll probably end up with some potential candidates that cause the crash

Comment: thanks a lot. 
found the problem.